# Enumerating installed certificates in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, certificate

How do you enumerate through installed certificates (all the certs you would see by running certmgr.msc) and inspect the serial numbers in vb script? My goal is to delete all certificates except one with a particular serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the CAPICOM library, specifically, the [`Capicom.Store`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388120.aspx) object. [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com) has an excllent example:

[List all certificates](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=listcert_vbs)

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to other solutions, PowerShell provides a simpler handling:

```psh
$serial = '...'

Get-ChildItem cert: -Recurse | ? {
  $_.GetType().Name -eq 'X509Certificate2' -and $_.SerialNumber -ne $serial
} | Remove-Item
```